# delete row while extends SQLiteOpenHelper

Tags: android, sqliteopenhelper

i was write the method to delete row....but, i don't know why, i can't delete row....
this is my the method...

```
public void clearDatabase() {
    openDataBase();
    try {
        int id=0;
        Cursor c = myDB.rawQuery("Select id from " + tablename +" asc", null);
        if (c.getCount() > 22) {
            c.moveToFirst();
            id = c.getInt(0);

            for(int i = 0;i<11;i++){
                int x = id+i;

                myDB.execSQL("delete from "+tablename +" where id = "+x , null);
            }

        }
        else 
        c.close();
        closedb();

    } catch (SQLiteException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

and this is the logcat: 
12-13 12:10:57.073: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(327): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.parser/com.parser.parse}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Empty bindArgs

Please help me!...Thanks before1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use

```
public void deleteEntry(long lRow) {

    ourDatabase.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + lRow, null);
}
```

in my SQLite DB to delete a row, where lRow is passed from my view activity.

EDIT

and here is my delete button in the view activity

```
String dRow = etSQLvRec.getText().toString();
        long lRow = Long.parseLong(dRow);

        DBase db1 = new DBase(this);

        try {
            db1.open();
            db1.deleteEntry(lRow);
            db1.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {

            String error = e.toString();
            Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
            d.setTitle("Cannot Delete");
            TextView tv = new TextView(this);
            tv.setText(error);
            d.setContentView(tv);
            d.show();
        }
```

etSQLvRec is a TextView that displays the _id of the record I'm viewing, I pass it so it deletes the record I'm viewing.